# Grid and adjacency matrix in java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, grid, adjacency-matrix

Need little help with my programming.

I'd like to create a grid with `n` columns and `n` rows. A also would like to show or print adjacency matrix.For start I did create some code, but the results are not correct, and I don't know hot to fix it. I need this grid to calculate shortest path, mutation of this grid, ...

The first `for` loop create a nice grid size `n*n`, but I don't know how to create links between naighbour nodes. The second code (which is in comment, create a adjacency matrix, but is not correnct -> node 3-4,7-8, 11-12 shouldn't be connected (if we have `4x4` grid), and in this code is missing last 4 nodes (if `n=4`).

Can someone tell me where did I fail in my coding :)?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Network_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns/rows");
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(input1.readLine());
        input1.close();
        int N = cols * cols;
        int[][] A = new int[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (i > 1
                    && ((cols == 0 && N % i == 0) || (cols > 0 && i % cols == 0))) {
                if (cols == 0) {
                    cols = i;
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.format("%3d", i);
        }
        System.out.println("\nAdjacency matrix:");

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
/*      
// If I try to create my "grid" with this code, I do not get true results
// The Matrix is incorrect
    for(int i=0; i<N-cols; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N-cols; j++){
            if((cols > 0) && (i % cols == 0)){
                A[i][i+1] = 0;
                A[i + 1][i] = 0;
            }else{
                A[i][i+1] = 1;
                A[i + 1][i] = 1;

                A[i][i+cols] = 1;
                A[i + cols][i] = 1;
            }               
        }
    }       
    System.out.println("Adjacency matrix2:");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + " ");
        }
            System.out.println("");
    }
*/
    }
}
```

Helo. I did some other approach and this work quite well for me right now. I know tis isn't the best solution, but it wokrs for now. Now I will etst if realy works...

```
public static int[][] make_grid(int cols) {
        int N = cols * cols;
        int[][] A = new int[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i][i] = 0;
            int left= i - 1;
            int right= i + 1;
            int upper= i - cols;
            int bottom= i + cols;

            if (left> 0)
                A[i][left] = 1;

            if (rigft% cols != 0) {
                if (right< N)
                    A[i][right] = 1;
            }

            if (upper> 0)
                A[i][upper] = 1;
            if (bottom< N)
                A[i][bottom] = 1;
        }
        return A;
    }
```

Comment: You're using an `int array` instead of a Node-Graph object.  You can't "link" between different positions in the `int array`.  Have you thought about making a rectangle graph class?

Comment: Hey. The link is mention for adjacency matrix. I did also create a scalefree network on base of this code. I just dont know hot to create grid and how to "connect" neighbours. I dont know hot to "disconnect" the last node anf first node in next line and how to include `N-cols` nodes in this matrix. I get 0 for last 4 nodes (if `N=4`)